# codeigniter - check session validity prior to form submission

Tags: codeigniter, session, session-timeout

In codeigniter, it seems that a form can be submitted even after a session has expired.

Example: I was about to fill out a form and left my computer for a bit. When I returned, I submitted the form successfully, and when I checked the database the userID was 0. So I refreshed the page and found myself redirected to the login page--the session had expired, and I could still submit the form. Doesn't seem like that should happen.

I've setup a function that should take care of it, but **I want to understand why a form can be submitted after the session expires, or if this points to something being wrong.**

```
function sess_valid() {
       $sess_timeout = now() - 3600; //3600 is the session expiry time
       $last_act = $this->session->userdata('last_activity');

       if($last_act <= $sess_timeout)
       {
        redirect('login');
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form can be submitted at any point in time. A form does not require session at all. A form is a section of a HTML document and it only requires valid HTML. In other words, everything's fine with your form.

After a form is submitted, it sends the data. This is where you have to act with your server side language - validate the form data.
In your case, as you already noticed, checking if session is alive is the right direction. Depending on the result of the check, you can redirect to login simultaneously saving the form data somewhere, and repopulating the form fields for user, after he/she gets logged in.

Comment: Accepted and upvoted because of your explanation. I figured as much about the form, but sometimes wonder when things seem too easy.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have to manually take care of the session check. You can do this as you did, at the level of the form validation run. For example:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE || !sess_valid())
```

Comment: I selected a different answer, but am upvoting this because it is helpful.